# Why am I receiving ELIFECYCLE errno 1 suddenly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, yarnpkg, discord.js

I've just moved my development environment over to Fedora. I've installed Node and NPM properly, but my run script isn't working. It exits immediately with errno 1 and no extra output. It works perfectly on my Mac and Windows desktop.

My npm-error.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~predev: biblebot@5.0.0
6 info lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~dev: biblebot@5.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/vypr/Code/BibleBot/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/vypr/bin:/home/vypr/bin:/home/vypr/bin:/home/vypr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~dev: CWD: /home/vypr/Code/BibleBot
10 silly lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'babel src -d build && node build/start.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle biblebot@5.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: biblebot@5.0.0 dev: `babel src -d build && node build/start.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.bundled/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid biblebot@5.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/vypr/Code/BibleBot
16 verbose Linux 4.13.9-300.fc27.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error biblebot@5.0.0 dev: `babel src -d build && node build/start.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the biblebot@5.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I noticed the problem was not with Babel but the script, so I ran it using `node` (it's a Discord bot) and it starts but immediately stops without any error.

I also tried the solutions I found here, but nothing has came to help. I've also tried yarn, but to receive the same error with a different format:

```
Trace: 
  Error: Command failed.
  Exit code: 1
  Command: sh
  Arguments: -c babel src -d build && node build/start.js
  Directory: /home/vypr/Code/BibleBot
  Output:

      at ProcessTermError.MessageError (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:186:110)
      at new ProcessTermError (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:226:113)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:30281:17)
      at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

My run scripts (I used dev):

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d build",
    "dev": "babel src -d build && node build/start.js",
    "start": "node build/start.js",
    "refresh": "git pull && babel src -d build && node build/start.js",
    "snyk-protect": "snyk protect",
    "prepare": "npm run snyk-protect",
    "test": "snyk test"
  },
```

I also saw other answers saying that this could be related to ports being already used. So I researched what ports discord.js uses (80 and 443), and tried to see if Python's SimpleHTTPServer failed using the ports. It ran perfectly (albeit I had to run as sudo, but even `sudo npm run dev` gives me the same problems).

My code before Babel's transpile:

```
import central from "./central";
import * as config from "./data/config";

import * as Discord from "discord.js";
const bot = new Discord.Client();

import CommandHandler from "./handlers/commands";
import VerseHandler from "./handlers/verses";

const commandHandler = new CommandHandler();
const verseHandler = new VerseHandler();

import settings from "./handlers/commands/settings";

bot.on("ready", () => {
    central.logMessage("info", "global", "global", "connected");
    bot.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        afk: false,
        game: {
            "name": "BibleBot v" + process.env.npm_package_version,
            "url": "https://biblebot.vypr.space"
        }
    });
});

bot.on("debug", (debug) => {
    if (config.debug) {
        central.logMessage("debug", "global", "global", debug);
    }
});

bot.on("reconnecting", () => {
    central.logMessage("info", "global", "global", "attempting to reconnect");
});

bot.on("disconnect", () => {
    central.logMessage("info", "global", "global", "disconnected");
});

bot.on("warning", (warn) => {
    central.logMessage("warn", "global", "global", warn);
});

bot.on("error", (e) => {
    central.logMessage("err", "global", "global", e);
});

bot.on("message", (raw) => {
    // taking the raw message object and making it more usable
    let rawSender = raw.author;
    let sender = rawSender.username + "#" + rawSender.discriminator;
    let channel = raw.channel;
    let message = raw.content;
    let source;

    if (config.debug) {
        // TODO: Replace this with user IDs.
        switch (sender) {
            case "vipr#4035":
                break;
            default:
                if (config.versionAdders.indexOf(sender) != -1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    return;
                }
        }
    }

    settings.languages.getLanguage(rawSender, (language) => {
        // channel.guild is used here because
        // of the possibility that DMs are being used
        // otherwise, i'd use guild.name
        if ((typeof channel.guild != "undefined") &&
            (typeof channel.name != "undefined")) {
            source = channel.guild.name + "#" + channel.name;
        } else {
            source = "unknown (direct messages?)";
        }

        if (sender == config.botname) return;
        if (channel.guild.name.includes("Discord Bot")) {
            if (raw.author.id != config.owner) {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (message.charAt(0) == "+") {
            const command = message.substr(1).split(" ")[0];

            let args = message.split(" ");
            const returnValue = args.shift(); // remove the first item

            if (returnValue == undefined) {
                args = null;
            }

            try {
                commandHandler.processCommand(command, args, language, rawSender, (res) => {
                    let originalCommand;

                    if (!res.announcement) {
                        channel.send(res.message);

                        Object.keys(language.commands).forEach((originalCommandName) => {
                            if (language.commands[originalCommandName] == command) {
                                originalCommand = originalCommandName;
                            } else if (command == "eval") {
                                originalCommand = "eval";
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Object.keys(language.commands).forEach((originalCommandName) => {
                            if (language.commands[originalCommandName] == command) {
                                originalCommand = originalCommandName;
                            }
                        });

                        bot.guilds.forEach((value) => {
                            if (value.name == "Discord Bots" ||
                                value.name == "Discord Bot List") return;

                            let sent = false;
                            const ch = value.channels.findAll("type", "text");
                            const preferred = ["misc", "bots", "meta", "hangout", "fellowship", "lounge", "congregation", "general",
                                "taffer", "family_text", "staff"
                            ];

                            for (let i = 0; i < preferred.length; i++) {
                                if (!sent) {
                                    let receiver = ch.find(val => val.name === preferred[i]);

                                    if (receiver) {
                                        receiver.send(res.message.replace(
                                            "+" + language.commands.announce + " ", ""
                                        )).catch(() => {
                                            // do nothing
                                        });

                                        sent = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        channel.send("Done.");
                    }

                    let cleanArgs = args.toString().replaceAll(",", " ");
                    if (originalCommand == "puppet" || originalCommand == "eval" || originalCommand == "announce") cleanArgs = "";

                    central.logMessage(res.level, sender, source, "+" + originalCommand + " " + cleanArgs);
                });
            } catch (e) {
                central.logMessage("err", sender, source, e.message);

                channel.send(e.message);
                console.error(e.stack);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                verseHandler.processRawMessage(raw, rawSender, language, (result) => {
                    if (!result.invalid) {
                        if (result.twoMessages) {
                            channel.send(result.firstMessage);
                            channel.send(result.secondMessage);
                        } else {
                            channel.send(result.message);
                        }

                        central.logMessage(result.level, sender, source, result.reference);
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                central.logMessage("err", sender, source, e.message);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
});


central.logMessage(
    "info", "global", "global", "BibleBot v" + process.env.npm_package_version +
    " by Elliott Pardee (vypr)");
bot.login(config.token);
```

My code after Babel's transpile:

```
"use strict";

var _central = require("./central");

var _central2 = _interopRequireDefault(_central);

var _config = require("./data/config");

var config = _interopRequireWildcard(_config);

var _discord = require("discord.js");

var Discord = _interopRequireWildcard(_discord);

var _commands = require("./handlers/commands");

var _commands2 = _interopRequireDefault(_commands);

var _verses = require("./handlers/verses");

var _verses2 = _interopRequireDefault(_verses);

var _settings = require("./handlers/commands/settings");

var _settings2 = _interopRequireDefault(_settings);

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } newObj.default = obj; return newObj; } }

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var bot = new Discord.Client();

var commandHandler = new _commands2.default();
var verseHandler = new _verses2.default();

bot.on("ready", function () {
    _central2.default.logMessage("info", "global", "global", "connected");
    bot.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        afk: false,
        game: {
            "name": "BibleBot v" + process.env.npm_package_version,
            "url": "https://biblebot.vypr.space"
        }
    });
});

bot.on("debug", function (debug) {
    if (config.debug) {
        _central2.default.logMessage("debug", "global", "global", debug);
    }
});

bot.on("reconnecting", function () {
    _central2.default.logMessage("info", "global", "global", "attempting to reconnect");
});

bot.on("disconnect", function () {
    _central2.default.logMessage("info", "global", "global", "disconnected");
});

bot.on("warning", function (warn) {
    _central2.default.logMessage("warn", "global", "global", warn);
});

bot.on("error", function (e) {
    _central2.default.logMessage("err", "global", "global", e);
});

bot.on("message", function (raw) {
    // taking the raw message object and making it more usable
    var rawSender = raw.author;
    var sender = rawSender.username + "#" + rawSender.discriminator;
    var channel = raw.channel;
    var message = raw.content;
    var source = void 0;

    if (config.debug) {
        // TODO: Replace this with user IDs.
        switch (sender) {
            case "vipr#4035":
                break;
            default:
                if (config.versionAdders.indexOf(sender) != -1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    return;
                }
        }
    }

    _settings2.default.languages.getLanguage(rawSender, function (language) {
        // channel.guild is used here because
        // of the possibility that DMs are being used
        // otherwise, i'd use guild.name
        if (typeof channel.guild != "undefined" && typeof channel.name != "undefined") {
            source = channel.guild.name + "#" + channel.name;
        } else {
            source = "unknown (direct messages?)";
        }

        if (sender == config.botname) return;
        if (channel.guild.name.includes("Discord Bot")) {
            if (raw.author.id != config.owner) {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (message.charAt(0) == "+") {
            var command = message.substr(1).split(" ")[0];

            var args = message.split(" ");
            var returnValue = args.shift(); // remove the first item

            if (returnValue == undefined) {
                args = null;
            }

            try {
                commandHandler.processCommand(command, args, language, rawSender, function (res) {
                    var originalCommand = void 0;

                    if (!res.announcement) {
                        channel.send(res.message);

                        Object.keys(language.commands).forEach(function (originalCommandName) {
                            if (language.commands[originalCommandName] == command) {
                                originalCommand = originalCommandName;
                            } else if (command == "eval") {
                                originalCommand = "eval";
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Object.keys(language.commands).forEach(function (originalCommandName) {
                            if (language.commands[originalCommandName] == command) {
                                originalCommand = originalCommandName;
                            }
                        });

                        bot.guilds.forEach(function (value) {
                            if (value.name == "Discord Bots" || value.name == "Discord Bot List") return;

                            var sent = false;
                            var ch = value.channels.findAll("type", "text");
                            var preferred = ["misc", "bots", "meta", "hangout", "fellowship", "lounge", "congregation", "general", "taffer", "family_text", "staff"];

                            var _loop = function _loop(i) {
                                if (!sent) {
                                    var receiver = ch.find(function (val) {
                                        return val.name === preferred[i];
                                    });

                                    if (receiver) {
                                        receiver.send(res.message.replace("+" + language.commands.announce + " ", "")).catch(function () {
                                            // do nothing
                                        });

                                        sent = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            for (var i = 0; i < preferred.length; i++) {
                                _loop(i);
                            }
                        });

                        channel.send("Done.");
                    }

                    var cleanArgs = args.toString().replaceAll(",", " ");
                    if (originalCommand == "puppet" || originalCommand == "eval" || originalCommand == "announce") cleanArgs = "";

                    _central2.default.logMessage(res.level, sender, source, "+" + originalCommand + " " + cleanArgs);
                });
            } catch (e) {
                _central2.default.logMessage("err", sender, source, e.message);

                channel.send(e.message);
                console.error(e.stack);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                verseHandler.processRawMessage(raw, rawSender, language, function (result) {
                    if (!result.invalid) {
                        if (result.twoMessages) {
                            channel.send(result.firstMessage);
                            channel.send(result.secondMessage);
                        } else {
                            channel.send(result.message);
                        }

                        _central2.default.logMessage(result.level, sender, source, result.reference);
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                _central2.default.logMessage("err", sender, source, e.message);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
});

_central2.default.logMessage("info", "global", "global", "BibleBot v" + process.env.npm_package_version + " by Elliott Pardee (vypr)");
bot.login(config.token);
```

Comment: I don't know what the issue actually is, but it seems that it's going to be revealed by your run script. Please edit your question to include that. Also, check out [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4943) on the nodejs/node repo which points to it being a problem with passing parameters wrong.

Comment: @l3l_aze Added to original. The secondary question I have is that why does the same run script work everywhere else without complaint but now that I'm on Fedora it errs? I'm sure the sh implementation isn't all that different, so it makes me wonder too.

Comment: Considering the fix it is kinda strange that it worked on Mac & Windows previously, lol. Thank you for updating with your results; glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding out what the problem was.

In line 2 of my original code, I meant to have `import config from "./config"`. Making that change fixed it perfectly.

For anyone else reading and having a similar issue, make sure that you're importing properly.